# Neither the property "patient" nor one of the methods in joining tables Symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying in Symfony 6 to join two tables by one relational column, where one table has OneToMany relation to the other.

This is my controller logic

```
#[Route('/admin/patients', name: 'app_patients')]
public function patients(PatientsRepository $patients, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{

    $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
        'SELECT patients, patientsInfo
    FROM App\Entity\Patients patients
    JOIN App\Entity\PatientsInformation patientsInfo
    WHERE patientsInfo.patientID = patients.id'
    );


    $data = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('main/tables.html.twig', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

my twig template

```
                                {% for item in data %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ item.patient.id }}</td>
                                    <td><i class="fas fa-user-nurse fs-5"></i> {{ item.patient.name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ item.patientsInfo.nationality }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ item.patient.unhcrID }}</td>
                                    <td>No</td>
                                    <td>{{ item.patient.creationDate|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
                                    <td>None</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button">More</a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
```

The error it throws is

> Neither the property "patient" nor one of the methods "patient()", "getpatient()"/"ispatient()"/"haspatient()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\Patients".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

learning some basic debugging techniques will help you learn what to do next. Something as simple as dumping the `data` value from within the template, would tell you what the internal structure looks like.

Before your loop (e.g. before `{% for item in data %}`) add a dump command:

```
{{ dump(data) }}
```

Then the structure will be apparent.

You can also use the php function `dump($data);` in your controller. This will add the variable to the Symfony toolbar for inspection. Using the php function `dd($data);` will dump the content to the browser directly and then halt the rest of the program execution (e.g. "dump and die").

See Symfony's docs for more information: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

Finally, You would benefit by using a repository method or querybuilder to use DQL to collect your data. Here is a query builder example:

```php
$patients = $this->entityManager
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from(Patients::class, 'patients')
    ->leftJoin('patients.patientInformation', 'information') // guessing on naming here
    ->select('patients', 'information')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Your result will be a collection of `patients`.

Assign that to the template as `['patients' => $patients]`

Loop that:

```
    {% for patient in patients %}
```

Now your variable make sense. Your `patient` is an instance of `Patients` and has all the properties and methods of it. You can reference each directly:

```
    {% for patient in patients %}
    <tr>
         <td>{{ patient.id }}</td>
         <td><i class="fas fa-user-nurse fs-5"></i> {{ patient.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ patient.patientInformation.nationality }}</td>
         <td>{{ patient.unhcrID }}</td>
         <td>No</td>
         <td>{{ patient.creationDate|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
         <td>None</td>
         <td>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button">More</a>
              <a class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
         </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

You should also consider changing your `Patients` entity to `Patient` as one instance of the class represents *one patient*, not the full collection.

Best of luck!